# Как выдернуть email из GET-запроса?

Tags: php, email

Подскажите, как можно выдернуть из GET запроса вот такого вида `bad.php?mail=alavama@mail.ru` email? Какой код нужно будет вписать в bad.php, чтобы переходу на него доставалось `alavama@mail.ru`, например. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как id выдергивать знаю, а как выдернуть email? Или то, что стоит после знака равно (=) в запросе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как ответ выше, но с поправочкой - без e

```
echo $_GET['mail'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_GET['mail'];
```

PHP надо выучить сначала, а потом уже писать!:)